# Posgres Record does not exits while fetching

Tags: python, postgresql, function, view

I am getting rows of records from database in a loop. in the loop there are also some select query where rerecords does not exits..

I wrote this view

```
CREATE view get_application_views AS
SELECT application_id, coalesce(SUM(views),0) as views FROM employer_applicationstats GrOUP BY application_id;
```

and then on this in the loop..

```
SELECT views FROM get_application_views WHERE application_id = '5605617';
```

for `application_id 5605617` there is no records exists, so my python scripts raises error and stop the loop.s

How can i handle this situation?

UPDATE:

```
def get_application_view(application_id):
    try:
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        sql_query = "SELECT views FROM get_application_views WHERE application_id = '"+str(application_id)+"';"
        cursor.execute(sql_query)
    except Exception as e:
        print e
        status = 0
        return status
    else:
            ver = cursor.fetchone()
            status = ver[0]
        return status
```

for the application_id = 5605617 it says ,

```
status = ver[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: How should we know? You didn't show any of your script.

Comment: check the update question now

Answer (score 1):

There is no `if` statement in your code:

```
def get_application_view(application_id):
        status='1'
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        sql_query = "SELECT views FROM get_application_views WHERE application_id = '{id}';".format(id=application_id)
        try:            
           cursor.execute(sql_query)
        except Exception as e:
           print e
           status = 0
        else:
            # do something
        return status
```

I also suggest using the `.format()` approach as it's much cleaner, particularly with SQL quotes.

Comment: I want this exception to be `handeled on Database side`, because i am getting data above `10k`, and doing this calculation on Python, I am getting `request timeout error` when it takes more than 30 sec in calculations.

Comment: Still getting `status = ver[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Comment: I'm not certain I totally understand the context, but how about just wrapping the try/except around the actual execution of the query? I updated my answer to demonstrate what I mean

Answer (score 0):

[cursor.fetchone()](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.fetchone) returns None when nothing is fetched. So your original code will look like

```py
def get_application_view(application_id):
    try:
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        sql_query = "SELECT views FROM get_application_views WHERE application_id = '"+str(application_id)+"';"
        cursor.execute(sql_query)
    except Exception as e:
        print e
        status = 0
        return status
    else:
        ver = cursor.fetchone()
        if ver:        
            status = ver[0]
        else:
            status = 0
        return status
```

Also, I prefer the cursor object creation and return statements to be take out from the try..except given in @celenius's answer.

We can convert the if..else.. block to a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) as `status = ver[0] if ver else 0`

Answer (score 0):

After reading out postgres function i chanages my code to something like this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_application_views(application_id integer, OUT views bigint)
RETURNS bigint
LANGUAGE sql
AS $function$
SELECT coalesce((select sum(views) as views from employer_applicationstats where application_id = $1 GROUP BY application_id), 0);
$function$
```

and

```
def get_application_view(application_id):
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        sql_query = "SELECT * FROM get_application_views('{id}')".format(id=application_id)
        try:            
           cursor.execute(sql_query)
        except Exception as e:
           return 0
        else:
            ver = cursor.fetchone()
            status = ver[0]
            return status
```

Thanks to @celenius